# How can I avoid "Minimum Pulse Width" slack violations in Quartus FPGA synthesis?

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, synthesis, quartus-ii

I am synthesizing a toy application on DE2, but I hit a timing problem (despite every inputs and outputs are clocked in my design). These violations are related to "minimum pulse width"...

How can I avoid such negative slack during FPGA synthesis ?

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
; Slow Model Minimum Pulse Width: 'CLOCK_27'                                                                     ;
+--------+--------------+----------------+------------------+----------+------------+----------------------------+
; Slack  ; Actual Width ; Required Width ; Type             ; Clock    ; Clock Edge ; Target                     ;
+--------+--------------+----------------+------------------+----------+------------+----------------------------+
; -0.500 ; 0.500        ; 1.000          ; High Pulse Width ; CLOCK_27 ; Rise       ; HEX0[0]~reg0
```

Comment: That relates to a clock - it looks like it's too fast?

Comment: No, I don't think so. It is about the shape of Clock_27

Comment: What constraints did you give for the frequency and duty cycle of CLOCK_27? What are the actual frequency and duty cycle you expect in your application?

Comment: 27 Mhz is set for frequency. The reports seem to say I can go much higher. Concerning duty cycle, I have 50/50 % and I can change this, if advised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think pjc50 has the right idea; have you edited the .sdc file 
"create_clock" statement?  it has a "waveform" keyword that gives a rise and fall time for the clock waveforem, and the above can happen if these are too close together (e.g. "{ 0.000 1.000 }").  Not to belabor the obvious, but it should be more like "{ 0.000 18.519 }" for a 50% duty cycle and a 27 MHz clock.

Comment: That is the solution. Thx !